# Are there any tools similar to XML Beans for 834 files in JAVA

Tags: java, apache, file, xmlbeans

I love the pleasure of dealing with XML files with XMLBeans objects... Now working with 834 files, i wonder if its a similar tool for 834 files

A flat file object will be helpful also

thanks
Chung

Answer (score 1):

I was curious - you may be lucky :)

Assuming, that '834' is an abbrevation for the HIPAA Benefit Enrollment and Maintenance
Transaction (834) that is based on the electronic data interchange standard, I looked around and found a project on SourceForge: [EDIReader](http://edireader.sourceforge.net/)

If I guessed wrong - leave a comment and I'll silently delete this answer ;)